# Using mage to sign a clickonce application with a code signing certificate

Tags: clickonce, mage

I keyed a Code Signing Certificate from Godaddy and downloaded to a build machine.  I then exported the certificate to a pfx file, then copied that file to my local machine and imported into my certificates.

I was then able to successfully sign my ClickOnce application using

```
mage -Sign "MyClickOnce.application" -CertFile "mycert.pfx" -Password mypassword
```

However when I go back to the original machine from which I created the CSR and downloaded the cert from godaddy, if I run the same exact code I get the following error:

**Internal error, please try again. A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.**

My only thought is that this machine cant "see" godaddy.  I'm kind of stuck on how to get past this error on this one machine.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever figure out how to fix this?